# Position spans within a p tag so one part stays on the left, the other on the right

Tags: html, css

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
#billingsummary span.billingitem {
    color: White;
    text-align: left;
}

#billingsummary span.billingvalue {
    text-align: right;
}

<p>
    <span class="billingitem">@Model.ProductName</span>
    <span class="billingvalue">$ <span id="billingproductcost">4.00</span></span>
</p>
```

So I'd like `billingitem` to be as far to the left as possible.

And I'd like `billingvalue` to be as far to the right as possible.

The outcome isn't what I want:

[image]

Comment: Text-align won't work in this case because what you are instructing the browser to do is align the text within the span.  The span is only as wide as the text because it is an inline element and therefore the alignment really has no effect.

Comment: [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-align) applies to block level elements, table cells and inline-blocks, so not for default `span`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use float:

```
#billingsummary span.billingitem { 
    color: white; 
    float: left; 
} 
#billingsummary span.billingvalue { 
    float: right; 
} 
#billingsummary p {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do float:right; and float:left; instead. The elements after that should include clear:both; if you want them to be below both of those items.

Answer (score 0):

what `text-align` does is align text inside a block element to the side specified:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#alignment-prop

Span are inline elements, so text-align has no effect for them. You should float them:

```
#billingsummary span.billingitem { 
    color: white; 
    float: left; 
} 
#billingsummary span.billingvalue { 
    float: right; 
}
```

Floating them you make them block elements and tell them to be in the extrem and out of the normal flow. If you have some problem with following elements you should `clear: both` them